# "Secret text" Git credentials not showing up in Jenkins project Source Code Management section

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am unable to see any `Secret text` credentials in the drop down in my Jenkins' project SCM section. I know that creating a `Secret text` credential from the drop down in SCM section is broken, but even if I create the credential by navigating to `Jenkins -> Credentials`, that credential does not appear in the drop down.

I've created every type of credential and the only type I see in the dropdown is `Username with password`. It seems like the dropdown in SCM filters out every credential that is not of this type.

The reason I need `Secret text` credentials in the SCM section is because I want to use a Github access token (and not my Github account username and password).

The following screenshot shows my global credentials where my `Secret text` credential is clearly present.
[image: Global credentials with Secret text credential present]

The following screenshot shows my project's SCM section's Git dropdown where only the `Username and password` credential is present.[image: Git SCM section with no Secret text credential present]

Jenkins version: `2.102`
Jenkins Credentials plugin version: `2.1.16`
Jenkins Git plugin version: `3.7.0`

Comment: @ScotTorch any chance you might consider marking my answer as the correct one? Thank you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't use the `Secret Text` credential for the SCM step because the Github Personal Access Token is only supposed to **replace your password**. Not your user *and* password. Meaning **your user is still required**. In the Github documentation [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) you'll see it reads:

> You can create a personal access token and use it **in place of a password**

And then below in section **"Using a token on the command line"** [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/#using-a-token-on-the-command-line) it reads:

> Once you have a token, you can enter it **instead of your password** when performing Git operations over HTTPS.

And it follows up with this example:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
Username: your_username
Password: your_token
```

If you extrapolate this to Jenkins, the sensible choice of credential type is still the `User with password` one.

So, simply create a credential of type `User with password` as you normally would and **use your personal access token for the `Password` field**.

[image: User with password credential using personal access token instead]

Comment: GitHub has announced that `GitHub will discontinue password authentication to the API` https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/ would that affect `Git PlugIn` ?

Comment: But why does the [Jenkins doc suggest to store tokens in secret field](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/#:~:text=Secret%20text%20-%20a%20token%20such%20as%20an%20API%20token). Is this really an issue on Jenkin's/Credential plugin's  side or the documentation is incorrect. The irony is that it specifically mentions GitHub Access tokens.

Comment: Fair point. I guess it's an issue with the Jenkins docs. I've so far used the `Username with password` credential type for Github personal access tokens, Bitbucket personal access tokens, Bitbucket application passwords and Gitlab personal access tokens. The secret text credential is suitable for when no username is required. Like when injecting a Google Maps API key.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the Credentials Bindings plugin, the *Build Environment* section of your build job *Configuration* page will include a new option to “Use secret text(s) or file(s)”. Enabling this option allows you add credential bindings where the *Variable* value will be used as the **name of the environment variable** that your build can use to access the value of the credential.

For example you create a secret: (the ***** = 12345)
[image]

You can use it in the following way in your build:
[image]

Output of `echo $VAR` in my case is `*****`. But you can use it as `12345` in your job. This is how you use secret text. The name says it all. The text remains secret but you can use it as unprinted variable in your job. This is for text, not for credentials.

If you want to reuse your credentials in your build it's recommended to use the "username and password conjoined". Here you can set a variable for your credentials. More info can be found [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs) on how you can split username and password.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I do not need to use this credential in the build itself. I'm using it for access to the Git repository via a Github access token. I've updated the question for clarity.

Comment: I'd recommend to use the GitHub plugin in jenkins instead of the Git plugin then. There you can import your own access token and use it: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin?preview=/37749162/82280592/manage-token.png

Comment: can we have multiple secrets separated by comma(,)?

Comment: I would recommend to put it in separate secrets